# Alamofire Accept and Content-Type JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to make a GET request with Alamofire in Swift. I need to set the following headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

I could hack around it and do it directly specifying the headers for the request, but I want to do it with `ParameterEncoding`, as is suggested in the library. So far I have this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, encoding: .JSON)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("Error: \(error)")
            println(req)
            println(res)
        } else {
            NSLog("Success: \(url)")
            var json = JSON(json!)
        }
}
```

`Content-Type` is set, but not `Accept`. How can I do this properly?

Comment: The best approach I can come up with right now is to add it to the `defaultHeaders` property of the `AlamoFire.Manager`

Comment: @David How would that go exactly? I tried `Alamofire.Manager.defaultHTTPHeaders().updateValue(value: "application/json", forKey: "Accept")` with no luck

Comment: You'll actually need to change it in the `manager.session.configuration. HTTPAdditionalHeaders` property.  Changing it there will make the change apply to all subsequent requests.  Another possibliity is to add a `Request` modeled on `validate` that allowed me to set a header on the fly.  That way you could change it for a single request.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up using `URLRequestConvertible` https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#urlrequestconvertible

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseUrlString = "someUrl"

    case Get(url: String)

    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
        let path: String = {
            switch self {
            case .Get(let url):
                return "/\(url)"
            }
        }()

        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseUrlString)!
        let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:
                           URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))

        // set header fields
        URLRequest.setValue("application/json",
                            forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        URLRequest.setValue("application/json",
                            forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        return URLRequest.0
    }
}
```

And then just:

```
Alamofire.request(Router.Get(url: ""))
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("Error: \(error)")
            println(req)
            println(res)
        } else {
            NSLog("Success")
            var json = JSON(json!)
            NSLog("\(json)")
        }
}
```

Another way to do it is to specify it for the whole session, check @David's comment above:

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration
         .HTTPAdditionalHeaders?.updateValue("application/json",
                                             forKey: "Accept")
```

Comment: This is an even better approach than my comment above.

Comment: The router answer now throws 2 errors in Swift 2.  On the `enum Router:`  we get `Type 'Router' does not conform to protocol 'URLRequestConvertible'` and on `return URLRequest.0` we get `Value of type 'NSMutableURLRequest' has no member'0'`.

Comment: @Craig.Pearce good one, changed to `NSMutableURLRequest`. I'm not able to test it right now, so let me know if it's still broken

Answer (score 6):

Example directly from Alamofire github page:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
         .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
         .response { (_, _, _, error) in
                  println(error)
         }
```

In your case add what you want:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
         .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
         .validate(Accept: ["application/json"])
         .response { (_, _, _, error) in
                  println(error)
         }
```

Comment: Nope, that gives me `Accept: */*`. I need it to be specifically `application/json`

Comment: `.validate(Accept: ["application/json"])` doesn't work either, XCode shows the following error: `Incorrect argument label in call (have 'Accept:', expected 'contentType:')`

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to use get method with query map and response type json

```
var parameters: [String:Any] = [
            "id": "3"  
        ]
var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get,
 parameters: parameters,
encoding: URLEncoding.queryString,headers:headers)
.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseData { response in     
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):  
                case .failure(let error):    
                }
```

Comment: for me setting encoding to queryString worked. thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
     ...      
}
```

it's work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
URLRequest.setValue("application/json",
                    forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
URLRequest.setValue("application/json",
                    forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```