# How to set Content-Type in swift3 alamofire

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

**I am sending data in JSON with content-type JSON but this shows me the content-type XML.
So the server could not read my request.**

**Also, that is the post request**

[image: See this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alamofire Accept and Content-Type JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374483/alamofire-accept-and-content-type-json)

Comment: Add this `request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")`

Comment: Already added you can see in the image

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani are you sure your API can both send JSON and XML responses?

Comment: Yes that is JSON API from Booker `https://apicurrent-app.booker.ninja/WebService4/json/Custome‌​rService.svc/custome‌​r`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `.responseJSON` which tells `Alamofire` that the response would contain `JSON`. Since the response is `XML` and not `JSON` in your case, `Alamofire` would throw an error. What you need instead is not to specify the response type and then an `XMLParser` to parse the data. One option is [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash). Your updated code would look something like this

```
Alamofire.request(request)
         .response { response in
            var xml = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)
         }
```

Comment: I am checking this but the api says me the response will be in json `https://apicurrent-app.booker.ninja/WebService4/json/CustomerService.svc/customer`

Comment: This link returns a `404`. Also, in your logs, it returns `500`. Might be something worth looking into to make sure you are getting a response from the server and that it is, in fact, in the right format

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is not an error of content-type. this is an error of data type.

I send the all value in the string but there is **need to send the data with data type**.

When I request with data type it automatically changed content-type in JSON.