# Alamofire post body format is not correct

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

I use Alamofire to call api methods. I use it like this

```
Alamofire.request("some api",
        method:method,
        parameters:body,
        encoding:URLEncoding.default,
        headers: finalHeaders)
        .responseJSON { (apiResponse) in
        ...
```

body is a Dictionary of Strings and Any. When I send a post request server gets something like this as body:

```
key1=StringValue&key2=intValue
```

While I need my body format be like this:

```
"key1":"StringValue","key2":intValue
```

What parameter is not set or is set wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

Set content type as JSON.

```
_ = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
```

Check this answer
[Alamofire Accept and Content-Type JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374483/alamofire-accept-and-content-type-json)

Comment: This is not the answer but helped me to find the answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to change the encoding type like this

```
Alamofire.request("some api",
        method:method,
        parameters:body,
        encoding:JSONEncoding.default,
        headers: finalHeaders)
        .responseJSON { (apiResponse) in
        ...
```